# Why RecyclerView view is not showing for firebase data return

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I want to return data from firebase and show it in my recycler view. But data is not showing and don't show any error also. I try to show local data in recycler view and that work fine. Mean not problem in adapter. I give all code in below, please help me.

how to solve this problem. I don't understand where is the problem

main activity code:

````
   private FirebaseDatabase database;
   private DatabaseReference reference;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

       RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.re);
       recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
       LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
       recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
       ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
       PostAdapter customAdapter = new PostAdapter(this, list);
       recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

       /*DataReturn dataReturn = new DataReturn("name", "namw","123","1","w","er"
       ,"fgh","ghj");*/

       //list.add(dataReturn);

      reference = database.getReference("posts");
       reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
               for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                   for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : ds.getChildren()){
                       DataReturn dataReturn = dataSnapshot.getValue(DataReturn.class);
                       System.out.println(dataSnapshot);
                       list.add(dataReturn);



                   }
               }

           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
               throw error.toException();

           }
       });
   }
} ```


my ModelView Class code:
``` public class DataReturn {
   String body,date,id,reaction,status,userId,title,image;

   public DataReturn() {}

   public DataReturn(String body, String date, String id, String reaction, String status, String userId, String title, String image) {
       this.body = body;
       this.date = date;
       this.id = id;
       this.reaction = reaction;
       this.status = status;
       this.userId = userId;
       this.title = title;
       this.image = image;
   }

   public String getBody() {
       return body;
   }

   public void setBody(String body) {
       this.body = body;
   }

   public String getDate() {
       return date;
   }

   public void setDate(String date) {
       this.date = date;
   }

   public String getId() {
       return id;
   }

   public void setId(String id) {
       this.id = id;
   }

   public String getReaction() {
       return reaction;
   }

   public void setReaction(String reaction) {
       this.reaction = reaction;
   }

   public String getStatus() {
       return status;
   }

   public void setStatus(String status) {
       this.status = status;
   }

   public String getUserId() {
       return userId;
   }

   public void setUserId(String userId) {
       this.userId = userId;
   }

   public String getTitle() {
       return title;
   }

   public void setTitle(String title) {
       this.title = title;
   }

   public String getImage() {
       return image;
   }

   public void setImage(String image) {
       this.image = image;
   }
} ```

my adapter class:

``` public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder> {

   Context context;
   ArrayList<DataReturn> list;

   public PostAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DataReturn> list) {
       this.context = context;
       this.list = list;
   }

   @NonNull
   @Override
   public PostAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent,false);
       //return new postAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
       return new ViewHolder(view);
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

       DataReturn dataReturn = list.get(position);
       holder.title.setText(dataReturn.getTitle());
       holder.content.setText(dataReturn.getBody());
   }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return list.size();
   }

   public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

       ImageView img; TextView title,content;
       public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
           super(itemView);
           //img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postImageView);
           title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_view_title);
           content = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_view_content);
       }
   }
}
````

Comment: Are you getting data from Firebase?

Comment: yes, Data is coming but not show in recycler View. my database json. https://hello-writer-2db52-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the thing, you are creating your RecyclerView and setting its parameters, and one of the parameters is that adapter that, in your case, requires the context and the list of items to be shown; you are passing an empty list at the beginning so that the recycler view won't show anything. Until that point, the thing is normal.

Now when you get back your data, you are updating the list you passed to the adapter, but the adapter won't know that you have updated the list; it won't check by itself; you need to **TELL** the adapter, you can do that in many ways:

You can do `customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after setting the list (I am assuming that you passed the list by reference, so the same list is being used in both your activity and your adapter).

Or you can do something better, which is to create a method in the adapter class that updates the list and triggers the changes in the adapter, something like that:

```java
//add this to your adapter
public void updateData(List<DataReturn> data){
    this.list = data;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and then in your activity call that method with the new list:

```java
...
 @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
               //create a new list to hold the new data
               List<DataReturn> result = new ArrayList<>();

               for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                   for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : ds.getChildren()){
                       DataReturn dataReturn = dataSnapshot.getValue(DataReturn.class);
                       System.out.println(dataSnapshot);
                       result.add(dataReturn);
                   }
               }

               // update the adapter after collecting all dataReturns
               customAdapter.updateData(result);
           }
...
```

I created a new list for the result to hold the new data and pass it to the adapter! (By the way, you can remove the list from your code and adapter constructor, and just initialize it to an empty one, then with each update, it will be replaced).